# efficiently split data into bins

Tags: matlab, performance

I want to split my `data` variable into different variables `a` `b` and `c`, and apply `mean` to the bins (1st dimension). Is there way to substantially (e.g. 1x order of magnitude) improve this code in terms of speed? General feedback welcome

```
data=rand(20,1000); %generate data
bins=[5 10 5]; %given size of bins
start_bins=cumsum([1 bins(1:end-1)]);
end_bins=cumsum([bins]);
%split the data into 3 cell arrays and apply mean in 1st dimension
binned_data=cellfun(@(x,y) mean(data(x:y,:),1),num2cell(start_bins),num2cell(end_bins),'uni',0);
%data (explicitly) has be stored into different variables
[a,b,c]=deal(binned_data{:});
whos a b c
  Name      Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1000             8000  double              
  b         1x1000             8000  double              
  c         1x1000             8000  double
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it in separate variables, rather than a single matrix with different rows or leaving it in the cell array?

Comment: yes... I'm trying to improve and learn about a library that requires the matrix to be split into a structure field. The awesome code snippets posted below illustrate to me that the design choice on that might not have been exactly optimal. The rest of the library requires those structure fields

Comment: A simple for loop is not an option ?

Comment: If you want to split a cell array into fields of a struct you can use [`cell2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) and thus avoid the intermediate variables

Comment: @obchardon a loop is implemented, but I want to go down the devils path and optimize by vectorizing @luis_mendo: sorry to be unclear. It's a cell array within a struct field. The above variables `a,b,c` represent such fields, I guess it's easiest assigned - either in a loop -  or using `deal`

Comment: update, good to know: Using `sparse()` does not seem to work for int16 variable types, which for me happens to be the case and excludes some answers

Comment: further update/FYI: apparently using bsxfun(@times) is not implemented in matlab2016a with int16

Comment: You can wrap your data with `double()` when passing into the accumulation function to avoid int16 type issues... given you're calculating the mean you're going to end up with doubles anyway?

Comment: @Wolfie you are absolutely right and that is an excellent point

Comment: < obligatory disclaimer about the potential memory impact of converting from int16 to double for large datasets >

Comment: @Wolfie I gave this some thought, I'm reducing the original rawdata to snippets _before_ converting (you infer correctly that RAM is the reason the datatype is int16 in the first place), that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`splitapply`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) (`accumarray`'s slightly friendlier little brother):

```
% Your example
data = rand(20,1000); % generate data
bins = [5 10 5];      % given size of bins

% Calculation
bins = repelem(1:numel(bins), bins).'; % Bin sizes to group labels
binned_data = splitapply( @mean, data, bins ); % splitapply for calculation
```

The rows of `binned_data` are your `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: I didn't know `splittapply` could work row-wise (or column-wise) with a data matrix. Good find!

Comment: @Luis as long as the grouping vector (row or column accordingly) matches the size, it sort of works like your favoured implicit expansion!

Comment: I see. I like it :-D

Comment: chose this answer because in my real use-case (data size 400x50000 and 50x bins) was actually consistently ever-so-slightly faster than the matrix multiplication solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Original question: splitting and averaging along *different* dims

The mean can be applied before the splitting, which reduces the data to a vector, and then [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can be used:

```
binned_data = accumarray(repelem(1:numel(bins), bins).', mean(data,2), [], @(x){x.'});
```

## Edited question: splitting and averaging along *same* dim

`accumarray`<sup>1</sup> does not work with matrix data. But you can use [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), which automatically accumulates data values corresponding to the same indices:

```
ind_rows = repmat(repelem((1:numel(bins)).', bins), 1, size(data,2));
ind_cols = repmat(1:size(data,2), size(data,1), 1);
binned_data = sparse(ind_rows, ind_cols, data);
binned_data = bsxfun(@rdivide, binned_data, bins(:));
binned_data = num2cell(binned_data, 2).';
```

---

<sup>But [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) does. See [@Wolfie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219902/2586922).</sup>

Comment: mea culpa, I messed up, I needed it in the 1st dimension, but if I read your (elegant) code correctly, this is easily adaptable. updated example code

Comment: I have to go now. I'll take a look later

Comment: Please see edit. In the mean time, you also got some very good answers :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use matrix multiplication:

```
r = 1:numel(bins);
result = (r.' == repelem(r,bins)) * data .* (1./bins(:));
```

If you want the output as cell:

```
result = num2cell(result,2);
```

For large matrices it is better to use sparse matrix:

```
result = sparse(r.' == repelem(r,bins)) * data .* (1./bins(:));
```

Note: In previous versions of MATLAB you should use `bsxfun`:

```
result = bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@eq, r.',repelem(r,bins)) * data , (1./bins(:)))
```

Here is the result of timing for three proposed methods in Octave:

Matrix Multiplication:

```
0.00197697 seconds
```

Accumarray:

```
0.00465298 seconds
```

Cellfun:

```
0.00718904 seconds
```

EDIT :
For a 200 x 100000 matrix :

Matrix Multiplication:

```
0.806947 seconds   sparse: 0.2331  seconds
```

Accumarray:

```
0.0398011 seconds
```

Cellfun:

```
0.386079  seconds
```

Comment: You might need a bigger example, timing results will be more representative if the code takes of order seconds to complete (not that I doubt simple multiplication is quickest).

Comment: OK, the result is different for different sizes.

Comment: it is still at least some indicator for very large time-effects. Would you run `num2cell` to convert rows to cell array and output into the different variables?

Comment: answered in main question, it just happens to be a circumstantial requirement for me

Comment: can somebody help me make this work in matlab2016a? Just replace all implicit operators with bsxfun?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple for loop, I don't see how another function can be faster in this case. The function `mean` must in any case read each value so...

```
for ii = 1:numel(start_bins)
    res{ii} = mean(data(start_bins(ii):end_bins(ii),:),1);
end
```

I'm not going to split the cell into multiple variables since a cell is intended exactly for this.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yups indeed I missed the dimension, thanks. I will benchmark the different solutions tonight to see, in this specific case, how bad a for loop is in comparison to a vectorized solution.